# Is it possible to change the magnifier factor?

Tags: settings

I’m visually impaired and am really liking elementary OS.  With that said, I am aware that eOS has a built-in zoom function (via super and +/-), however, I’m wondering if it is possible to change the factor at witch this increases and decreases.

Turns out I’m pretty blind yall!

So, I’m actually a computer science major, needless to say, I’m familiar with computers.  Perhaps, if someone can tell me what to change, I’d be happy to change whatever it is that controls the max in and max out.

I imagine I’ll have to do something with the terminal, as long as I know what, and where, needs modification, I’m sure I can do it.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This can be fixed by using keyboard shortcuts. By default, the super key plus the + key should zoom in or magnify any areas the mouse cursor is located. To zoom out, you should use combine the super key with the -key.